# angularJS - getting x & y positions from mouseclick in div

Tags: javascript, position, angularjs

I made a function that should add an item on the position I clicked inside a div. Now the problem with this function is, every time I click, it takes the x & y position of the document, not the x & y position inside the div. So what I actually want, is that the top-left corner of my div should give x=0 & y=0, but I don't know if this is possible? And I guess there is another way to do this..

```
$scope.addOnClick = function(event) {
        $scope.items.push( {
            "label": "Click",
            "value": 100,
            "x": event.x-50,
            "y": event.y-50,
        })
}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to change `event.x` to `event.offsetX` and `event.y` to `event.offsetY`

You didn't add the template definition but I'll add it just in case:

```
<div ng-click="addOnClick($event)"></div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I knew it would be something as easy as that :D & yeah, I already added the template definition, but I was sure everything was alright there.. Thanks alot mate!

Comment: Be careful Firefox doesn't have offsetX. [Use layerX for Firefox.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878471/return-coordinates-of-mouse-click-on-html5-canvas-using-javascript-mouse-events)

Comment: Firefox now has `offsetX` and `offsetY`, but they do not seem right.

Answer (score 5):

In html file, use:

```
<div (click)="test($event)"></div>
```

And in the function in the ts file::

```
function test(e){
 console.log(e.clientX);
 console.log(e.clientY);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For those on angular who are using dragging libraries and want the position of the element that was dragged:

```
<div ng-click="OnDrag($event)"></div>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.onDrag($event){
      console.log("X ->",$event.originalEvent.pageX,"Y ->",$event.originalEvent.pageY)

 }
```